# Can I safely use a utf8 connection with utf8mb4 columns?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

As long as all tables in my database are not migrated to utf8mb4, is there a risk of continuing to use a utf8 connection?

I thought keeping the utf8 connection until all the tables are migrated.

The underlying question is: how long will it take to make changes on very large tables (hundreds of GB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all the data is in the 3-byte utf8 subset, utf8 and utf8mb4 are identical.

The connection parameters (including `SET NAMES`) specify the encoding in the *client*.  The column/table definition says what encoding is handled in the columns.  MySQL will convert between those as you `INSERT` or `SELECT`.  Again, as long as all the data is utf8 subset, the conversion is possible (effectively a no-op).

Answer (score 7):

Some examples of how MySQL performs the conversion if you trying to insert the sentence :
« This emoji  is a cat »

1 - with a utf8 connection in a table utf8 : MySQL truncates the string from character 4 bytes:
« This emoji »

2 - with a utf8 connection in a utf8mb4 table : MySQL replaces the 4 bytes character with "???? "
« This emoji ???? is a cat»

3 - with a utf8mb4 connection in a utf8 table : MySQL replaces the 4 bytes character with "? "
« This emoji ? a cat »

Comment: Good examples of what happens when utf8mb4 is needed, but there is a mismatch between connection and column.